# Passive FTP transfers in Windows 3?

Tags: windows-3.x, software-recommendation, data-transfer, virtual-machine

Does anybody know if there have ever been any passive FTP Clients for Windows 3.x? I ask because I think that might be a good way to transfer data between retro computers and modern computers. The difficulty for me is that all of my Windows 3.x machines are *virtual* machines. Sure, I could probably figure out a way to configure my host firewall, but I'd rather find a way to just install a passive FTP client and get it over with.

(My host machine runs GNU/Linux, and dealing with IPTables can sometimes be a real nightmare.)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that WS_FTP LE supports it (when connecting / creating a profile, click "Advanced" and check "Passive Transfers"), and I believe that Netscape Navigator 4.x will also do passive mode by default for FTP. It may not have the features you want from a "real" FTP client, but it does support browsing and downloading files.

Comment: Will Kermit work on a modern computer?  Just kidding.

Comment: @WalterMitty absolutely. Once I was working with a DOS machine that had a floppy drive that "sort of" worked (probably out of alignment). I put ten copies of KERLITE.EXE on a floppy so that one would actually work, then used that to download the rest of what I needed to the hard drive :)

Comment: @WalterMitty The protocol should be easily reimplemented, if it hasn’t been ported already.

Comment: @WalterMitty Have a look at https://www.kermitproject.org/

Comment: @WalterMitty - that was my first thought. My second thought was a virtual null modem cable.